# How to test Vimeo API during development

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

**How can I develop and test for the Vimeo API, without actually uploading to my account?**

I am trying to develop a website which lets user uploads video files, sends them straight through Vimeo, and embeds them. Afterwards the videos can through the site be manipulated, for example deleted. Developing and testing this will result undoubtedly in many requests and uploads to my account, resulting in test files in my main account, incomplete videos, etc. Maybe even an incorrect API call could result in the loss of one of my videos...

You cannot create a separate account for this without paying for PRO again (I asked), and I cannot find any sandboxes or mock API endpoints. How can I separate these dev/test activities from production?

*Edit to add: In the reference there's an option to 'try it out', but this too actually impacts your account.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Vimeo API works with live data, I would recommend creating a separate free Vimeo account for development purposes. There are differences between account types, of course, however for what you describe (file upload, video deletion, embed code retrieval) you could mock all that up with a free basic account. Differences between Vimeo accounts are found here:

https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/228068968-Compare-Vimeo-plans

Once you're ready to work with your "actual" account, just swap out any tokens and client ids.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Sadly, many options are still unavailable with this method (setting privacy, applying embed presets, etc). Guess this is as good as it gets. Thanks!